# Proof in Georgii of $\mathbb E(XY) = \mathbb E(X) \mathbb E(Y)$ for independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I'm reading "Introduction to Probability and Statistics" by Georgii, and can't figure out how to formally show one of the steps of the proof of $\mathbb E(XY) = \mathbb E(X) \mathbb E(Y)$.

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P} \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E} $
Let $X,Y:(\Omega,F,\P)\to \mathbb R$ be independent random variables so that $X(\Omega)$ and $Y(\Omega)$ are at most countably infinite, and so that the expected value exists for both.
Let $X,Y$ be independent.

The proof (slightly altered) (Theorem 4.7 (d) in the book):
$$
\begin{align}
{}\E(XY) 
\\&= \sum_{z} z \P(XY=z)
\\&=\sum_{z\neq 0} z \sum_{x\neq 0} \P(X=x,Y=z/x) \\&= \sum_{x\neq 0 , y\neq 0 } xy \P(X=x)\P(Y=y) \\&= \E(X)\E(Y)
\end{align}
$$

I'm having trouble with step:
$$
\sum_{z\neq 0} z \sum_{x\neq 0} \P(X=x,Y=z/x) = \sum_{x\neq 0 , y\neq 0 } xy \P(X=x)\P(Y=y) 
$$

I guess the idea is that substituting $z/x$ by $y$:
$$
\begin{align}
&{}\sum_{z\neq 0} z \sum_{x\neq 0} \P(X=x,Y=z/x) 
\\&{}= \sum_{x\neq 0} \sum_{z\neq 0} z \P(X=x,Y=z/x)  
\\&{}= \sum_{x\neq 0} \sum_{\frac zx \neq \frac 0x} x\cdot \frac zx \P(X=x,Y=\frac zx)  
\\&{}= \sum_{x\neq 0} \sum_{y\neq 0} xy \P(X=x,Y=y)
\end{align}
$$

While it certainly looks obvious enough, I'm looking for a proof that precisely states the sets over which the sums run, and explains the equivalence I'm having trouble with.

A possible start:
$$
\begin{align}
&{}\E(XY) 
\\&= \sum_{z\in \mathbb R  \\ \exists: x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega): xy = z} z \P(XY=z)
\\&= \sum_{z\in \mathbb R  \\ \exists: x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega): xy = z} z \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)\\ x\neq 0} \P(X=x,Y=z/x) 
\\ &=
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Just a remark:
$$\mathbb{E}[XY] = \sum_{x\in X(\Omega),y\in Y(\Omega)} xy \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$$
follows directly from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Joint_distributions , so if you are allowed to use this more general version, then you can skip the two first equalities.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen That result certainly is practical. I'd have to prove it though, and I fear that the idea there is almost identical if not more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z \neq 0$ we have:

$\mathbb{P}(XY=z)= \mathbb{P}(XY=z, \bigcup_{x \in X(\Omega)}\{X=x\})=\mathbb{P}( \bigcup_{x \in X(\Omega)}\{XY=z,X=x\})= $

$\sum_{x \in X(\Omega)}\mathbb{P}(XY=z,X=x)=\sum_{x \in X(\Omega), x \neq 0}\mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)$.

Since for $z=0$, we get $z\mathbb{P}(XY=z)=0$, we have:

$\sum_{z \in X(\Omega)Y(\Omega)}z\mathbb{P}(XY=z)= \sum_{z \in X(\Omega)Y(\Omega)}z \sum_{x \in X(\Omega), x \neq 0}\mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)$

where $X(\Omega)Y(\Omega)= \{ z \in \mathbb{R} : z=xy, x \in X(\Omega), y \in Y(\Omega)  \}$

By [Fubini's theorem](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~wichura/Stat304/Handouts/L10.sums2.pdf), we can interchange the sums in the last term to get:

$\sum_{x \in X(\Omega), x \neq 0}\sum_{z \in xY(\Omega)}z \mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)= \sum_{x \in X(\Omega), x \neq 0}\sum_{\frac{z}{x} \in Y(\Omega)}\frac{z}{x}x \mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)$

$=\sum_{x \in X(\Omega), x \neq 0}\sum_{y \in Y(\Omega)}yx \mathbb{P}(Y=y,X=x)=\sum_{x \in X(\Omega)}\sum_{y \in Y(\Omega)}yx \mathbb{P}(Y=y,X=x)$.

Comment: @Sudix check my edit

Comment: The argumentation by Fubini was still quite a leap for me, but I've got it now! I.e. we have 
$$\forall x\in X(\Omega):\left( \sum_{z \in X(\Omega)Y(\Omega)}z \mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)
=
\sum_{z \in xY(\Omega)}z \mathbb{P}(Y=z/x,X=x)\right)
$$ because the statement $$\forall z  \in X(\Omega)Y(\Omega):\left( z\not\in xY(\Omega)\implies \mathbb P (Y=z/x)=0\right)$$ holds (because of  $z\not\in xY(\Omega)\land \mathbb P (Y=z/x)\neq 0 \implies \exists y\in Y(\Omega): y=z/x \implies z=xy\in xY(\Omega)\quad \unicode{x21af}$)

Comment: Thanks for you time and explanation!

Comment: Correct. Glad I could help :)